# QR Codes Recognition Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, qr-code, decoding

I need to develop an application which detects QR codes with Visual Studio 2010 and OpenCV. I am very new in this topic. Can someone explain in simple words the steps of the decode algorithm and the procedure to detect the patterns in a QR code? I have read the steps in the ISO/IEC 18004:2000 document but I don't understand well. Thanks in advance

Comment: At CodeProject, there is an [Open Source QRCode Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/qrcode.aspx) written in C# and it is compatible with Visual Studio 2010. I'm not sure why you want to use OpenCV as that seems more complicated than necessary. You are going to have to read and understand [ISO/IEC 18004:2000(E)](http://raidenii.net/files/datasheets/misc/qr_code.pdf) for encoding and decoding. If you don't understand how to utilize a Reed Solomon at least (for error correction), then use a library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to use OpenCV to draw a square when a QR code is detected, so I would like to locate the finder patterns of a QR code and to know what the steps are to do it.

Comment: @Lucia: That's a totally different question.

Comment: Yes, the language I am using is C++

Comment: OK. Is not the decode algorithm what I have to search? Do you know where I can find some information which explains how to detect QR codes in an image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QR Codes Recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912474/qr-codes-recognition)

Comment: Yes, I have asked the same question but in order words to explain better my problem. Should I delete this question?