# Computer vision: marker shape and way to detect it

Tags: opencv, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, emgucv

I want to develop a marker based augmented reality app, and I've chosen emgu as OpenCV wrapper because is the only framework I found that supports Mono for Android and Monotouch (if you know other frameworks I'll be happy to consider them, if Mono is supported).
I'm developing on windows with a webcam now, and so far I've detected the marker with FindChessboardCorners, using a chessboard as marker. I get the poins and drawing a bitmap in perspective over the chessboard, 3D comes later.

For my app I would like to use, as marker, a QR code, or specifically the 3 squares (with a square inside) that the QR code us as marker (that are the same for every QR code).

What's the best (and fastest,it should work with a cam) way to pass an image and a mark image (the QR code markers in BW) and get the markers positions like FindChessboardCorners?
Or should I stick to the chessboard?

Can you point me to an example, or give me a hint on how to proceed?

Thanks!
mattia

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911953/qr-codes-recognition-algorithm

Comment: not really, I don't need to decode the QR, I just want to do glyph recognition, and the glyphs to be the 3 main markers that are part of the QR code. I'm not interested in the 'inside' of the QR, but just to recognize it and their position. thanks anyway

Comment: I guess the point is that you might be able to use one of those generic QR libraries to get the position of the code. I know it doesn't solve your problem, but it is related information.

Comment: I think this question would be easier to understand if you provide an image of the sort of marker you expect to be able to detect, or some of the ideas you are considering.